# SwiftUI Memory Management

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm relatively new to SwiftUI (about 1 month of coding right now). I'm working on application which supports user login (email/facebook/google), what is important, it shows login/registration screen for not authorised user and rest of the app for user which is logged in. Of course user authorisation persists between app launches. To decide which view show to user I made such code in View served as starting by AppDelegate:

```swift
struct StartingView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppGlobal
  // Use 1 for main app view and 2 if user needs to login or create an account
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      if appState.presentedView == 1 {
          // AppView not wrapped in NavigationView as NavigationView is inside already
          AppView()
      } else if appState.presentedView == 2 {
        NavigationView {
          LoginView()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I launch my app and I'm not logged in it takes about 80 MB of RAM, and after logging in RAM  usage raises to about 130MB.

When I run my app as already logged in user it takes about 60MB. I assume that parts of LoginView persists after `appState.presentedView` changes. MemoryGraph doesn't show any memory leaks (sometimes it shows small leaks of single types, definitely not 50MB)

If I log out and go back to the LoginView app memory usage stays almost still, so itl looks like this behaviour is one way from LoginView -> AppView

My question is, how to prevent such behaviour and make my app use less memory directly after logging in. Is my views switching approach bad?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In Xcode Debug Navigator make View Memory Graph Hierarchy after login and you'll find what remains in memory. Then you'll know what should be cleaned.

Comment: I can't see anything worth attention under first tab (named with my app name), so I assume it has to be deeper. Is there any way to compare two memory graphs? Then I would be able to compare before and after login memory states.

Comment: This is normal and not a problem. If you are seeing activities that cause memory to steadily grow and never shrink, then that's a problem. But what you've described is not unusual in iOS. Modern OSes allocate memory in very non-intuitive ways, and apps generally will not release memory until there is memory pressure in the system. It is extremely difficult to nail down precisely how much memory an app is actually using in a meaningful way. The important thing is whether memory usage steadily grows over time or is stable.

Comment: Having started development on an Apple ][+, and having spent a lot of time in embedded development where a few kB is a fortune, it's hard for me to fathom a world where I say "eh…50MB? That's normal." But here we are.

Comment: @RobNapier, thanks for answer. I also did profiling of my app and tested the moment od view change. XCode doesn't mark any memory leaks, so I guess it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly unrelated to your memory issue, but you don't need the ZStack to surround your `if` block.

```
@ViewBuilder var body: some View {
    if appState.presentedView == 1 {
        // AppView not wrapped in NavigationView as NavigationView is inside already
        AppView()
    } else if appState.presentedView == 2 {
        NavigationView {
          LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

If you're on the latest iOS/XCode, I believe that you can even drop the `@ViewBuilder`.